# Show Socket.io Result in Select Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, socket.io

I emit query result with below code;

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
          socket.on('socketfabrika', function(fabrika) {
            console.log();
            console.log("**********************************");
            console.log("Selected Fabrika: " + fabrika);
            console.log("**********************************");
            console.log();

            connection.query("SELECT kumes FROM report WHERE fabrika = ? GROUP BY kumes DESC ", fabrika, function(err, rows) {
              if (err) console.log(err);
              else {
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                  var row = rows[i];
                  console.log("**********************************");
                  console.log("Possible kumes: " + row.kumes);
                  console.log("**********************************");

                  io.emit("sel_kumes", row.kumes);
                }
              }
            });
          });
        });
```

Then, on the client side, I'm trying to show query results in select box,

```
<form id="form_kumes">
    <select  multiple>
      <option id="sel_kumes"></option>
    </select>
</form>
```

But when I emit data to select box, it's always adding new value side by side in the select box,

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
 socket.on('sel_kumes', function(rows) {
      console.log(rows);
 $('#sel_kumes').append($('<option></option>').text(rows));
});
</script>
```

because of this line;

```
$('#sel_kumes').append($('<option></option>').text(rows));
```

---

If I change the script as;

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
 socket.on('sel_kumes', function(rows) {
      console.log(rows);
 $('#sel_kumes').text(rows);
});
</script>
```

Then, select box show only one result.

**How can I show all the results I get from server(*1st part of question*) and then refresh the select box If new value emitted?(*2nd part of question*)**

Comment: can you show the output of `console.log("Possible kumes: " + row.kumes);`

Comment: Output is;  `Possible kumes: 2` and `Possible kumes: 1`. May be I only emit once with this line; `io.emit("sel_kumes", row.kumes);`

Comment: `io.emit()` emits the same number of times the loop is ran. How do you want the output to be shown on slect box?

Comment: I want to see both '1' and '2' on select box but now, only '1' show. If I use  `append()` and new data comes, values adding to select box side by side as '1' and '2' but when another data comes, '1' and '2' are remains and new values adding to their side. I just want to see last called data, but not only one of them, all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`io.emit` is called the same number of times the loop is ran hence no problem with emitting and recieving.

What you are doing wrong is appending text to the same option everytime. Hence showing all text together side by side.

For multiple options to be displayed on client side, there should be multiple options too. What you have done is opposite of that.

Change html to:

```
<form id="form_kumes">
   <select  multiple id="sel_kumes">
   </select>
</form>
```

Now create number of options same as number of times response is recieved.

```
socket.on('sel_kumes', function(rows) {
      console.log(rows);
      var sel = document.getElementById('sel_kumes');
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.id = //give whatever id you have to give to options but make sure 
               //every options should have unique id
      opt.innerHTML = rows;

      //now append to sel div
      sel.appendChild(opt);

});
```

You can use jquery syntax in place of javascript as suitable.

**EDIT:** Answering to your 2nd question

There are many ways to do that one of them is instead of deleting the old select DOM create a new one and create options from beginning. Also for preventing to send values repeatedly you could just emit once using array.

*On server side:*

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i];
    console.log("**********************************");
    console.log("Possible kumes: " + row.kumes);
    console.log("**********************************");

    array.push(row.kumes);          
 }
 io.emit("sel_kumes", array);
```

*On client:*

```
socket.on('sel_kumes', function(array) {
      console.log(rows);
      var formm = document.getElementById('form_kumes');

      $("#sel_kumes").remove(); //removing element select

      var sel = document.createElement('select');
      sel.id = "sel_kumes";

      for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
          var opt = document.createElement('option');
          opt.innerHTML = array[i];

          //now append to sel div
          sel.appendChild(opt);
      }

      //finally append to parent form
      formm.appendChild(sel);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. This line has typo; `var opt = document.createElement('options');` I changed `('options')` as `('option')` and it worked. But still there is a problem. Now, everytime I emit, select box shows both '1' and '2' but still remains old datas when new data emitted. How can I overwrite the data to select box?

Comment: @erayaras you should always edit you question if asking something new or ask another question. But still check the edit anyway, it will work.

Comment: Thank you again, it works. Btw, `multiple` tag exist at line  `<select  multiple id="sel_kumes"></select>`  but select box turn to dropdown. I solved this with adding `sel.multiple="multiple"; sel.size="3";` after `sel.id = "sel_kumes";`